# Angular - mark a matInput invalid as default

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app written with Template Driven Forms and has two input fields which has to be marked as invalid immediately after loading the component when both of them are empty.
Input fields can get a default value with [(ngModel)] - myData.fieldA and myData.fieldB.
When both of them is empty or null, both of them should be marked as invalid. When at least one of them is getting filled, the inputs do not need to mark as invalid in the future.

I have the following code:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-small">
            <input matInput [required]="isFilled(myData)" [(ngModel)]="myData.fieldA">
        </mat-form-field>
```

When the input fields are getting loaded, they are not marked as invalid. After I click in them, enter no data and navigate away, it gets marked as invalid.
Is there any way not to update it only when they are touched but immediately?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: when you say mark as invalid means add the ```ng-invalid``` class to input if there is no value inside?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. You can add  `[ngClass]` to your input field and bind that to `css` marking the input as invalid (say, adding a `border:1px solid red` or something similar).
So when the input is prestine (not touched yet) and when it is invalid marking will be activated on initialization.

Here is a code-snippet demonstraing this:

```
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              name="firstName"
              [(ngModel)]="model.firstName"
              #firstName="ngModel"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': firstName.invalid }"
              required
            />
          </div>
```

Here is a [link to the code snippet in action via stackblitz](https://angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-pwsoge.stackblitz.io/)